# Git Bash - How do I get rid of old output after start?

Tags: bash, git

I wanted to activate conda environment by entering "conda activate" in Git Bash and got the CommandNotFoundError message with information on how to enable conda. I tried to follow the information given, but this did not work so well for me and I ended up with a bunch of old output showing in Git Bash whenever I start it. Other than that it seems to be working fine. Also later I learned to activate the environment using "source activate". Tried reinstalling Git Bash after deleting the Git directory, it did not work.

Conda version 4.5.10.

How do I get rid of this output print out on start?

This is what I see everytime I run Git Bash:

```
bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3etcprofile.dconda.sh: No such file or directory
bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda                                                                                                                                                                                                activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user wit                                                                                                                                                                                               h

    $ echo ". C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

or, for all users, enable conda with

    $ sudo ln -s C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/                                                                                                                                                                                               conda.sh

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

    $ conda activate

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

    $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH                                                                                                                                                                                                in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

    export PATH="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^


bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda                                                                                                                                                                                                activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user wit                                                                                                                                                                                               h

    $ echo ". C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

or, for all users, enable conda with

    $ sudo ln -s C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/                                                                                                                                                                                               conda.sh

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

    $ conda activate

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

    $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH                                                                                                                                                                                                in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

    export PATH="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^


bash: C:ProgramDataAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory

DELL@DELL MINGW64 /
$
```

Comment: Can you look in your home directory (just type `cd`) for a "hidden" file `.bashrc` (not really hidden,  `ls` will show the file when you use the option `-a`).
In that file you might have lines like `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`. Replace the `\` with a '/' (or eith `\\`) or remove the complete line.

Comment: Thank you so much Walter A, worked like a charm.

Comment: Than I will post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks again, for the record I ended up removing the line entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is generated by files in your `.bashrc`.

Look in your home directory (just type `cd`) for a "hidden" file `.bashrc` (not really hidden, `ls` will show the file when you use the option `-a`).
In that file you might have lines like C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh. Replace the `\` with a `/` (or with `\\`) or remove the complete line.
Windows understands the forward slash.